# Not returning the target items in the list when clicked on the item

Tags: javascript

How can I get the target item alerted when clicked using pure JavaScript (no jQuery)? Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code? Currently the JavaScript version is not working.

I used jQuery which works fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
});
```

Javascript bit (not working):

```
var action_list_ul = document.getElementById('li');
action_list_ul.addEventListener("click", set_ua_value);

function set_ua_value (e) {
  if(e.target && e.target.nodeName == "A") {
        console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
    }

}

<ul >
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post the code you tried....

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting an li with Id while id is not given to li!
Try giving id to and the write that id in getElementById. Also need to give a node name as you are checking that in if condition.

Comment: I tried that it dint work. I was getting javascript errors. Also, i want to try it without id like i did using jquery.